# Why is the pressure correction added in the Van der Waals equation?

Tags: gas-laws, intermolecular-forces, equation-of-state

Since real gas particles experience attraction to each other, that means the pressure must be less from what we would expect. So why do we have to add a term to correct it?
For example, in the correction for volume, we subtract a term to find the effective volume or the "real" volume. So, it follows that the "real" pressure must be less than the given one and so, should we not subtract a term?

This is mostly with regard to solving problems based on this law, where the values of pressure, volume, $a$ and $b$ are given

Comment: The Van der Waals  model was a crude method for adding some "fudge factors" into the ideal gas equation based on a theoretical justification. The Van der Waals model is by far not the best model for empirical data fitting. See Wikipedia article [Real Gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_gas)

Comment: So you basically say that the parameter would/should always be negative, right? Well, is it?

Comment: ".. real gas particles experience attraction to each other .." that is a very (too) simplistic statement. If you get the particles sufficiently close together, they *always* repel each other.

Comment: I was told that  the factor "a" is multiplied considering only the attraction so I framed it that way

Comment: @Karl  Interestingly, while atoms/molecules do repel each other at sufficiently close range, in gases that repulsion is entirely entropic.  I.e., neutral gas atoms/molecules are always in the attractive range when it comes to the pair potential. You can squeeze atoms/molecules sufficiently close to reach the repulsive region of the pair potential, but if you get them that close they are no longer in the gas phase.

Comment: Doesn't the "a" term make the pressure less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider the vdW equation as the deviation from the ideal gas state equation $pV_\mathrm{m} = RT$.

If you look at the vdW equation

$$\left(P+\frac a{V_m^2}\right)(V_m-b)=R T$$

you can easily see why the corrections have  their signs.

---

The pressure term correction has the positive sign,
as the real gas has  due molecule cohesion  **smaller** volume than  an ideal gas at the same pressure. **Like if it was under bigger pressure than it really was**.

Increasing $p$ term by a positive correction leads to lower predicted volume than for ideal gas, at the same pressure, because of cohesive force.

$$V_m=\frac {R T}{\left(P+\frac a{V_m^2}\right)}$$

The correction simulates this bigger pressure the ideal gas would need to get the same vol.

---

The volume term correction has the negative sign,
as the gas has at the given volume
higher pressure due molecule own volume.

Decreasing $V$ term by a negative correction leads to higher predicted pressure than for ideal gas, at the same pressure, because of own molecule volume.

$$P=\frac {R T}{(V_m-b)}$$

Comment: Smaller volume would mean more pressure than expected so the term should be subtracted?

Comment: @AnanyaPateriya  Smaller volume here means smaller atomic/molecular volume, not smaller container volume.  I.e., the particles themselves take up less of the space, so the "free volume" is greater, hence the pressure is lower.